# replace the empty fields from the output of "grep" with a string

Tags: text-processing, grep

I am using "grep" in a while loop (to read line by line) a long document (this long file contain multiple paragraphs,each paragraph starts with a date/time).

The purpose is to find certain phrase and print or echo the paragraph's date/time beside that phrase. How can I "echo" or "print" the letters "NULL" when grep can't capture the phrase. For example:

Let's say we have these three paragraph in the file (test.txt):

```
 20170101,05:00 AM, I am using grep to read certain phrase1 in a long document. 
 20170102,09:30 AM, I am using grep to read certain phrase2 in a long document. 
 20170103,05:30 AM, I am using grep to read page in a long document.
```

How can I echo or print a "certain phrase" and date time and if "certain phrase not available replace the output by NULL so the output as follow:

```
 20170101,05:00 AM,certain phrase1
 20170102,09:30 AM,certain phrase2
 20170103,05:30 AM,NULL
.
.
.
```

I use the following:

```
while read -r line; do
date=$(grep -c "201*")
phrase=$(grep  -Eo "certain phrase")

echo $date,$phrase
done < test.txt
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
while read -r line; do
  date=$(grep -Eo  "201.{12}.M," <<< "$line")
  phrase=$(grep  -Eo "certain phrase" <<< "$line")
  echo "${date}${phrase:-NULL}"
done < test.txt
```

You were reading the line, but not grepping against it. I tweaked the regex on the first grep to match the date part (instead of `-c` counting it). The last piece to the puzzle was to echo the $phrase variable with [parameter expansion](https://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Shell-Parameter-Expansion.html#Shell-Parameter-Expansion) to replace an empty value with the word "NULL".

Comment: Woww!! This is great solution. Thank you Jeff so much. Actually, I forgot the flag -ne after echo to print the output on the same line. I have one problem. Why  the output of echo -ne "${date}${phrase:-NULL}" is in the opposit direection? I mean it output phrase first or null then date/time although the command is to output dsate time first?

Comment: It outputs the date first for me, on your sample data. I didn't use `-ne`, but even with those options, it prints the date & phrase for each match, in sequence.

Answer (score 2):

Instead of `grep`ping in `while`, do all in a single `sed` script:

```
sed 's/\( *[0-9]*,[^,]*,\).*\(certain phrase[^ ]*\).*/\1\2/;t
  s/\( *[0-9]*,[^,]*,\).*/\1NULL/' file.txt
```

`sed` already handles the line-by-line for you, and in each line the script executes a replacement with the `s` command:

The first part `[0-9]*,[^,]*,` is supposed to match the date string. By surrounding it with `\(\)`, we can reuse it in the replacement as `\1`

The same for the second `\(\)`, containing the phrase and trailing non-blanks (adapt if necessary), which is referred to as `\2`. Everything else is thrown away.

If this replacement was done, the `t` command jumps to the end of the script, as we are done. If no replacement could be done, everything after the date is replaced by `NONE`

Comment: Thank you, very much. I highly  appreciate if you explain the command a bit.

Comment: That's a pretty straightforward script. If the first substitution matched and substituted something, you're done (`t`). Otherwise, proceed with the second substitution.

Comment: Added a little more verbose explanation, if you are not that familiar with `sed`

Answer (score 2):

I'd suggest something like

```
awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS=","} 
  /201/ {
    if (match($0,"certain phrase")) {
      print $1, $2, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1)
    } else {
      print $1, $2, "NULL"
    }
  }' file
```

Testing with your input data:

```
$ awk 'BEGIN {OFS=FS=","} 
>   /201/ {
>     if (match($0,"certain phrase")) {
>       print $1, $2, substr($0,RSTART,RLENGTH+1)
>     } else {
>       print $1, $2, "NULL"
>     }
>   }' file
 20170101,05:00 AM,certain phrase1
 20170102,09:30 AM,certain phrase2
 20170103,05:30 AM,NULL
```

Answer (score 0):

```
perl -lne 'print /^((?:.+?,){2})/, /\h\K(certain\h+phrase\d+)/ ? $1 : "NULL"' < test.txt
```

---

Here we get the first two comma-delimited fields and then look for "certain phrase". If it is found, use it else "NULL" is used.